# DNS not resolving after configuring it with BIND

Tags: dns

I have a new VPS with CWP installed. This is the file for my domain:

```
; Generated by CWP
; Zone file for erpuno.cl
$TTL 14400
erpuno.cl.      86400      IN      SOA      erpuno.cl.      contacto.erpuno.cl.      (
                2019050600      ; serial, todays date+todays
                        86400 ;refresh, seconds
                        7200 ;retry, seconds
                        3600000 ;expire, seconds
                        86400      )

erpuno.cl. 86400 IN NS ns1.erpuno.cl.
erpuno.cl. 86400 IN NS ns2.erpuno.cl.

erpuno.cl. IN A 45.7.228.32
vps.erpuno.cl. IN A 45.7.228.32
ns1.erpuno.cl. IN A 45.7.228.32
ns2.erpuno.cl. IN A 45.7.228.32

localhost.erpuno.cl. IN A 127.0.0.1

erpuno.cl. IN MX 0 erpuno.cl.

mail IN CNAME erpuno.cl.
www IN CNAME erpuno.cl.
ftp IN CNAME erpuno.cl.
; Add additional settings below this line
_dmarc  14400   IN  TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none"
```

But the DNS is not resolving. I can't access de URL and DNS lookup services don't find it. What am I doing wrong?

When I run dig erpuno.cl, I get:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-73.el7_6 <<>> erpuno.cl
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23843
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;erpuno.cl.                     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
erpuno.cl.              14400   IN      A       45.7.228.32

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
erpuno.cl.              86400   IN      NS      ns1.erpuno.cl.
erpuno.cl.              86400   IN      NS      ns2.erpuno.cl.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.erpuno.cl.          14400   IN      A       45.7.228.32
ns2.erpuno.cl.          14400   IN      A       45.7.228.32

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon May 06 21:43:27 -04 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 122
```

Everything seems normal. And both the config file and the zone file have no errors. 
From my PC I can ping the IP of the server, but not the domain. But from the console of the VPS I can ping the domain. 
The firewall has the ports open, so that's not the issue either.
Any ideas??

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" 1) You are probably offtopic here since your question has nothing to do with programming. You will probably have better luch on [sf] or [su] but read their own help section to see how to ask a good question 2) saying anywhere "it is not working" (or equivalent) without providing details about what you attempted **exactly**, what unexpected answer you got, and what expected results you wanted instead, put people wanting to help you in the uneasy case of trying to read your mind about your use case. So you need far more details for a good question.

Comment: Also more specifically on the DNS: 1) always use `dig @nameserver` to troubleshoot problems and make sure to understand the difference between an authoritative and a recursive nameserver 2) if you use Bind, use `named-checkconf` and `named-checkzone` or equivalent for other nameservers; also look at your logfiles to see what can be wrong 3) use online testing tools: https://zonemaster.net/ and https://dnsviz.net/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your resolv.conf file have the following lines:
domain yourdomain
nameserver ipaddr(of the machine with the dns server installed)